# nginx Expires header based on mime type for proxied content?

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

My setup uses a map to define different `Expires` headers for various static files (based on their mime type). For proxied content (`uwsgi_pass`), I use a static `Expires` header:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  7d;
    text/css                   180d;
    application/font-woff2      1y;
    application/pdf             1y;
    ~image/                     1y;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  example.com;
    
    location / {
            uwsgi_pass django;
            expires 7d;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/(css|fonts|images|pdf|html)/ {
            root /var/www/django/static/;
            expires $expires;
    }
}
```

Using the map (via the `$expires` variable) for proxied content does not work. Is there any way for nginx to identify the mime type of proxied content in order to make this work?

```
location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        expires $expires;
}
```

**(Edit)** As Alexey suggested, I did this:

```
map $upstream_http_content_type $expires2 {
         default                    off;
         text/html                  2d;
         text/plain                  20d;
         text/css                   180d;
}

location / {
        uwsgi_pass      django;
        expires $expires2;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is still no `Expires` header added to the content delivered via uwsgi.

Comment: Try `map $upstream_http_content_type $expires2 { ... }` with `expires $expires2;`

Comment: Thank you – this is what I am looking for, but unfortunately, this configuration still creates no `Expires` header for proxied content (added the code to my question).

Comment: You need to check the `Content-Type` header using `curl -I`. If it's like `Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8` it will not match your map, and you may want to use a regex instead.

Comment: That did the trick! The `Content-Type` header did contain the encoding, and changing the map entry to `~text/html 2d;` solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was provided by Alexey and Richard in the comments. I had to use a different nginx variable, and a regex for (at least) the map entry for HTML files:

```
map $upstream_http_content_type $expires2 {
         default                    off;
         ~text/html                  2d;
         text/plain                  20d;
         text/css                   180d;
}

location / {
        uwsgi_pass      django;
        expires $expires2;
}
```